# Whether there is an isolated system, it will enter equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

For a thermodynamically isolated system, will it eventually move toward thermal equilibrium? Will there be exceptions to the system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a closed system be a non-equilibrium system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330171/)

Comment: Yes, think you.